# How to initialize SharedPreferences 2.0.15 in flutter? (Dart - Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am using `shared_preferences: ^2.0.15` and saving my values locally.
When I change my screen and get my values, I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7g6U.png).

How can I initialize SharedPreferences correctly?

[Video](https://youtu.be/UcDPYyGRaa4)

```
  late SharedPreferences _preferences;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocalData();
  }

  Future getLocalData() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the video you shared.

You're just missing to call the `getLocalData` method inside the LoginViewModel.

I'd suggest adding a line inside your `loginRequest` method to call `getLocalData` method. Well, don't forget to await.

```dart
await getLocalData();
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

actually  you are not fetching data from your shared preference
you have to get the data that u saved

first set data that you want to save

```html
addStringToSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('email', "email@email.com");
}
```

then in your second screen you can get your data

```html
  late SharedPreferences _preferences;
  late String email;  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocalData();
  }

  Future getLocalData() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // for exemple you saved a string value with key ='email'
    email= _preferences.getString('email');
  }
```

check this : https://medium.flutterdevs.com/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127